# UDF in check constraint -- downside?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, constraint

I have a table where all actions affect single rows (insert and update, no delete's but if there were, they would be individual as well).  I'm considering using a UDF in a check constraint so I can make sure that a field value is only used in combination with another value (two FK's, the first time A=1 is used, B=x becomes fixed, so that if x = 4 then A=1 can never be matched with B=3 or anything except 4).

What are the downsides of doing this, other than the neligible additional time spent when inserting/updating the row?

UPDATE: The application doesn't provide a mechanism for changing either column A or B after the row has been created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store A and B columns in a separate table. Make sure your table has a primary key on A, and a unique constraint on (A,B) Refer to (A,B) from your table. The primary key on A will guarantee only one B per A. The foreign key without ON UPDATE CASCADE will make sure B does not change as long as the row is referred from the child table.

Answer (score 3):

UDFs that access other tables should generally be avoided in CHECK constraints (*).

There is almost no use case where they will behave entirely as expected by the user, there is almost certainly not a single SQL engine that implements them correctly according to the semantics as prescribed by the standard for CHECK constraints, brief, if you do this you're almost certainly headed to being the next in line to post yet another "CHECK constraint not working" question on some forum somewhere.

You said that "triggers seem more heavy duty".  You're right.  The problem is that you expect your engine to be able to infer all that "heavy duty" from your "simple" constraint declaration.  That expectation is unwarranted.

(*) As always, the exception is of course the people who "know what they're doing".  But if you were among those, you wouldn't have needed to ask anything in the first place.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your remark that "UDFs that access other tables should generally be avoided in CHECK constraints" - as surely that would be the other way around? ...a UDF that does a `SELECT` from the _same table_ as the causative `INSERT` or `UPDATE` is going to behave strangely compared to doing a `SELECT` from an entirely unrelated table, no?

Comment: It is related to the semantics of a CHECK constraint, which are that the CHECK expression must be satisfied by all rows in the table on which it is declared.  Updates to *other* tables mentioned in a CHECK constraint could potentially invalidate this condition, meaning that such updates *should* be rejected in order to maintain full integrity.  But that typically isn't implemented.

Comment: The same applies to the case where the (access to the) "other table" is hidden away in some UDF.  Updates to the other table can change the outcome of the UDF, which could invalidate the CHECK constraint itself, meaning such updates should be rejected once again.  But this is even harder to detect because of what happens in the UDF itself.