# What is the current state (2022) of using UDFs in a CHECK constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, check-constraints

SQL Server allows the use of User-Defined Functions (UDFs) in `CHECK` constraints - which has a number of use-cases - which I won't get into - but I was recently faced with implementing a non-trivial business/domain constraint that validated data in one table based on non-unique, non-key data from another table - which means the constraint cannot be implemented using any of the built-in constraints (`FOREIGN KEY`, `UNIQUE`, or a normal row-value based `CHECK` constraint).

My immediate go-to was a `TRIGGER`, as [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers) states that `TRIGGER` objects are the intended way to implement non-trivial constraints:

> DML triggers are most useful when the features supported by constraints cannot meet the functional needs of the application. [...] Unlike `CHECK` constraints, DML triggers can reference columns in other tables. For example, a trigger can use a `SELECT` from another table to compare to the inserted or updated data and to perform additional actions, such as modify the data or display a user-defined error message.

Hang a second: Microsoft wrote *"Unlike `CHECK` constraints, DML triggers can reference columns in other tables"* - but that's misleading! `CHECK` constraints *can* reference columns in other tables indirectly via a UDF.

...so methinks there's a bit of vague and outdated information out there - so let's do more research to see if `CHECK` constraints with a UDF is the right way to go or not...

[image]

...well, it seems that UDFs in `CHECK` constraints seem have a bad rep: with critical remarks concerning poor performance and their lack of formal correctness (*a winning combination*...), but I noticed that the articles and posts I read, including practically all of the Google search results concerning UDFs and `CHECK` constraints was just *old*...

- The [#1 Google search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQopP.png) for "sql server check constraint udf" is an article dating back to **2001** - which doesn't give any performance advice, but the fact this is still the top result shows there's a lot of old and outdated information out there that people today might think is still current.

  - > https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column
    > The ANSI SQL standard lets you use subqueries in CHECK constraints, but SQL Server doesn't support this functionality. However, if you're using SQL Server 2000, you can write a user-defined function (UDF) that performs an existence check against both tables and returns 1 if a row exists in either table and 0 if no row exists.
- [A **2006** DevX.com article](https://web.archive.org/web/20090613062352/http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/31985/0/page/3) for SQL Server 2000 and 2005 demonstrates using a pair of UDF-based `CHECK` constraints to solve the problem of `CHECK` constraints on dependent data not being revalidated when a potentially integrity-breaking `UPDATE` is run - however the article [goes on to say that SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106122244/http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/31985/0/page/4)'s snapshot-isolation feature means that invalid data can still find its way into the database.
- [A **2009** StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1036217/159145) has [an answer describing a UDF-based `CHECK` constraint running 100x slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038685/159145) than non-`CHECK`-based approaches.

  - A common refrain in the other answers - and the comments on those other answers - is a vague warning that a UDF in a `CHECK` constraint is "slow" - but most of the commentators don't provide an explanation or qualification - nor do they even say if "UDF" refers to a deterministic, non-table-reading function (e.g. a string format validation function) - or a `SELECT`-wrapping function - as I would expect a string format validation function to not significantly affect query or batch performance.
  - [A follow-up SqlBlog.com article about that very StackOverflow post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090705043824/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx) provides `SET STATISTICS` data, but I noticed the article doesn't share the full query plans and crucially: only looks at performance from a 128,000+ row `INSERT` statement - if an application only does single-row `INSERT` DML then I'd expect to see the UDF+`CHECK` perform very similarly to the FK approach.

    - This SqlBlog article then links to [a 2008 article that demonstrates the UDF+`CHECK` approach *not working*](https://web.archive.org/web/20090607213532/http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/02/07/using-a-udf-in-a-check-constraint-to-check-validity-of-history-windows-start-end-date-windows.aspx) when the UDF reads from the same table that a multi-row `UPDATE` is applied to.
- [A **2011** SpaghettiDba.com article](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) where the author describes how using Scalar UDFs in `CHECK` constraints causes row-by-agonizing-row evaluation of the UDF (still better than `TRIGGER` objects, of course).
- [A **2012** post on Dba.StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/udf-in-check-constraint-downside) also gives vague warnings:

  > UDFs that access other tables should generally be avoided in CHECK constraints [...] There is almost no use case where they will behave entirely as expected by the user, there is almost certainly not a single SQL engine that implements them correctly according to the semantics as prescribed by the standard for `CHECK` constraints.
- [A **2014** StackOverflow post about SQL Server **2008**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693571/custom-function-with-check-constraint-sql-server-2008) has highly-upvoted answers, which links to the aforementioned SqlBlogs.com article.
- [In a **2016** article Erik Darling described how using Scalar UDFs in `CHECK` constraints breaks parallelism](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/).

...which predates significant (albeit *recent*) changes to SQL Server w.r.t. how UDFs are handled:

- SQL Server 2017 added [Interleaved Execution for Multi-Statement Table Valued Functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-interleaved-execution-for-multi-statement-table/ba-p/385417) which I wonder might have implications for Scalar UDFs as Scalar UDFs and MSTVFs are very similar (compared to Inline TVFs).
- SQL Server 2019 [added inlining of Scalar UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining).

However authoritative information is hard to come-by, so I'm unsure what, **as of SQL Server 2019 or SQL Server 2022**, the current state of UDFs-in-`CHECK` constraints is, with respect to both performance and correctness, in both single-row and multi-row DML scenarios:

- Deterministic Scalar UDF in a `CHECK` that doesn't read any data, but is parameterized on a column value (e.g. a string validation function using only `LIKE` and `CHARINDEX`).
- Scalar UDF in a `CHECK` that does a `SELECT * FROM $table`, where `$table` is the *same table* that the `CHECK` constraint is applied to.
- Scalar UDF in a `CHECK` that does a `SELECT * FROM $table`, where `$table` is a different table (i.e. not the same table that the `CHECK` constraint is applied to).

---

<sub>As an alternative to UDF-in-a-`CHECK CONSTRAINT`, [I've been reading about using Indexed Views as a way of effectively implementing certain classes of database-wide (i.e. cross-table) integrity constraints](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) which are *always* enforced when any DML modifies data in any of the included tables, whereas `CHECK` constraints only take effect on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, but not `DELETE` (so `CHECK` constraints cannot be used to block `DELETE` DML) - but I'm curious if anyone has any experience with the technique.</sub>

Comment: What do you have against using triggers? A well-written trigger will nearly always outperform a UDF for multi-table constraints, because they are set-based. I have myself written, and seen, multiple answers on [so] regarding the indexed view trick, but never used it in anger. It's a very good if obscure trick, and probably the most performant

Comment: @Charlieface my _main_ reason for avoiding triggers in this project is that this project uses a lot of `UPDATE` and `MERGE` dml with the `OUTPUT` clause used extensively - [and the presence of triggers breaks those operations completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table) - and (as far as I know) we can't disable triggers for a single session separately from the others or use them like deferrable-constraints. Also, a trigger doesn't just reject DML: it can also have writes and side-effects of its own... argh

Comment: I'll admit the point about `OUTPUT` (although you can use `OUTPUT ... INTO` but that would take a lot of rewriting clearly). In this case the trigger would just have an `IF EXISTS (Failing Rows Here) THROW ....` which is unlikely to cause extra writes, only reads. If I were you I'd go for the indexed view (although you need to be careful not to have funny `SET` options such as `ANSI_NULLS OFF`). Whichever solution you use must have well-indexed base tables to even have a hope of performing efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer. [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16#inlineable-scalar-udfs-requirements) to inline scalar function specifically states it cannot be in a computed column or check constraint.

> The UDF is not used in a computed column or a check constraint definition